# Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. Problema con Datatables en C#

Tags: c#, datatable

¿Cómo puedo obtener el registro de mi fila seleccionada? Lo que me gustaria es que al seleccionar una fila esta seleccion me regrese el registro para después obtener su `Id` y por último hacer una actualización en caso de alguna modificación.

Coódigo actual del método para modificar:

```
DataGridViewRow row = dataTabla.CurrentCell.OwningRow;
string value = row.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

> Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

Solo que ese error me sale al inicio ni siquiera puedo entrar a la pantalla donde está la tabla y no se porqué lo ejecuta al incio si debería de ejecutarse al seleccionar una fila. Es un método de tipo `cellValueChanged`.

Comment: David, de pronto estas confundiendo el funcionamiento del evento CellValueChanged, por que este se lanza cuando el valor de la celda cambia, no cuando se selecciona la celda. Entonces si al iniciar tu aplicación le asignas datos al DataGridView, CellValueChanged va a ser ejecutado inmediatamente por que los valores de la celda van a empezar a cambiar justo en ese momento.

Comment: @Weimar Yamit Perez conoces al gun evento que pueda utilizar para que solo se ejecute una vez que se haya cambiado el valor de mi fila en mi datagridview

Comment: Si la idea es capturar cuando el usuario seleccione la fila o la celda, intentaría con alguno de estos 2: `SelectionChanged`, `CellClick`. Puedes encontrar un poco más de ayuda en la documentación de MSDN. https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

Para que puedas seleccionar la fila que deseen en el `DataGridView` hay un evento que se llama `RowCommand` dale doble clic luego y mandarlo asi:

```
 protected void DtgSolicitudes_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        DtSet = new DataSet();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
        con.Open();
        DtgSolicitudes.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = DtgSolicitudes.SelectedRow;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_BuscarSeguimiento", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("OPT", 2);
        SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("periodo", "");
        SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("oficina", "");
        SqlParameter p4 = new SqlParameter("rubro", row.Cells[1].Text);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p4);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Text);
        TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Text);
        TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3].Text);
        TextBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[4].Text);
        TextBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[5].Text);
        TextBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[6].Text);
        TextBox7.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[7].Text);
con.close();
    }
```

Comment: Aquí debes cerrar la conexión cuando termines de ejecutar la instrucción SQL, o dará errores la próxima vez que intentes ejecutar este código.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la recomendacion @MauricioAriasOlave.
si me puedes ayudar en mi pregunta que realize :
http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60323/autentificacion-window-iis-asp-net/60385#60385

Comment: Pierro, no creo poder personalmente ayudarte, pero, si la respuesta publicada no ha resuelto tu pregunta, deja un comentario en la respuesta de la persona que te respondió. Si tienes mas detalles, edita tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es guardar el Id, utiliza el evento `RowEnter`. Después utiliza el valor de `e.rowIndex` para conocer el índice de la fila seleccionada:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        idDeFila = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Id"].Value;
    }
```

Como alternativa, puedes ahorrarte guardar el Id cada vez que selecciones una fila y comprobar los cambios cuando vayas a validar la fila. Usa para ello el evento `RowValidating`. Dentro del método puedes hacer todas las comprobaciones que necesites para decidir si guardas los cambios o no:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(seCumplenCondicionesDeGuardado){
          //guardar fila o hacerlo en el evento RowValidated, que se lanzará inmediatamente después
        }
        else e.Cancel = true; //cancela el evento de validación de fila
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si el valor de la celda es nulo genera ese error. Debes verificar que el valor no sea nulo:

```
if (row.Cells["Id"].Value != null)
```

o bien:

```
if (object.ReferenceEquals(row.Cells["Id"].Value, null) == false)
```