# Autentificacion window IIS ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web, iis

Buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar estuve desarrollando un autentificacion de window con el lenguaje **asp.net** la cuestion esque si funciona y cuando ingreso a la pagina me sale el nombre del usuario que se logea.

El problema esque cuando subo mi pagina a un IIS no aparece el nombre del usuario logeado sino del IIS quisiera que me puedan ayudar.

Ya que cuando ejecuto desde mi Codigo Fuente si me funciona pero cuando lo subo al IIS no me sale el nombre de usuario de window logeado me sale

**DefaultAppPol**

Alguien que me puede ayudar por favor. he intentado de todo pero no me logra salir

Si es posible o no para que me puedan ayudar.

Solo el problema es cuando subo al IIS

**HTML LOGIN.**

```
<%

string strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
string clientIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(strHostName).GetValue(1).ToString();
//txtIp.Text = (clientIPAddress);
txtUsuario.Text = System.Environment.UserName; 

%>
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
    <title>.:: Sistema de Usuarios | FINANCIERA QAPAQ S.A. ::.</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style4.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var usuario = document.getElementById('<%=txtUsuario.ClientID%>');
        usuario.readOnly = true;
    </script>
<body>
    <center>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
          <div class="group">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsuario" runat="server" Width="250px"  MinLines="1" MaxLength="15" readonly  CssClass="form-control" class="highlight"  for="inputSuccess3"   ></asp:TextBox>
         <label></label>
  </div>

                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnLogin" Width="250px"  Onclick="btnLogin_Click" CssClass="btn btn-danger"  Text="Iniciar Session" />


         </form>
 </center>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/bootstrap.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>    
 <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>    
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/index4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**WEBCONFIG.**

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="DesbloqueoUsuario.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />



    </system.web>




  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="con"  connectionString="server=10.0.101.85\instbdd01; database=Seguridad;  user id=SA; password=SA123456789*;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="conn"  connectionString="server=10.0.101.85\instbdd01; database=BatCliente;  user id=SA; password=SA123456789*;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

  </connectionStrings>
    <applicationSettings>
        <DesbloqueoUsuario.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="DesbloqueoUsuario_localhost_WebService" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://localhost:56117/WebService.asmx</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="DesbloqueoUsuario_localhost1_WebService2" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://localhost:56116/WebService2.asmx</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="DesbloqueoUsuario_localhost9_WebService3" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://localhost:56117/WebService3.asmx</value>
            </setting>
        </DesbloqueoUsuario.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings />
        <client />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**problema en el IIS**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CUANDO EJECUTO EN MI PC**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta añadir esta linea en tu web.config dentro de la seccion `<system.web>` : `<identity impersonate="true" />`

Comment: @Pikoh gracias por comentar pero ahora me sale este error en mi codigo fuente cuando ejecuto:

Error HTTP 500.24 - Internal Server Error
Se ha detectado una configuración de ASP.NET que no se aplica en el modo integrado de canalización administrada.

Comment: Intenta ir a la configuración de tu IIS y realizas estos pasos: Click derecho en tu aplicacion/Administrar aplicacion/Configuracion Avanzada/En `Grupo de Aplicaciones` selecciona `Classic .NET AppPool`

Comment: Listo de ahi que hago si le encontrado esa opcion

Comment: lo movi me salio este error:

Línea 15:       <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />

Comment: Vale,si quieres que vaya contra 4.5 no puedes usar el classic .net apppool. Intenta otra cosa, dejalo como estaba (cambia el Grupo de Aplicaciones a lo que tenía y quita del web confing e. identity impersonate) y despues, en lugar de esta linea `txtUsuario.Text = System.Environment.UserName;` intenta con esta otra `txtUsuario.Text=Context.User.Identity;`

Comment: Context.User.Identity.Name; le puse asi ahora me sale en blanco

Comment: Pues a ver si alguien mas acostumbrado a trabajar con asp.net puede ayudarte. Yo trabajo con aplicaciones de escritorio el 99% del tiempo,siento no poder ayudarte mas :)

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo :)

Comment: @Pierro, tengo una inquietud. Si estas trabajando con autenticación Windows que función cumple el botón `Iniciar Sesión`. Ya que estoy asumiendo que cuando el usuario abre el navegador el ya debe estar logueado contra el sistema operativo (entonces no necesitaría un botón para iniciar sesión). Te lo pregunto es para darme una idea de lo que estas haciendo.

Comment: si efectivamente @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez cuando abre la pagina automaticamente ya debe aparecer el nombre del usuario logeado en window no ese boton solo es un nombre que da clic y ingresa pero muchas gracias mas bien en ves iniciar session el nombre debio decir entrar .
pero la cuestion esque cuando ejecuto de mi maquina normal aparece el problema ocurre en el IIS cuando lo subo me muestra asi.
si tienes un correo te lo paso todo mi codigo que realize.

Comment: @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez si fueras tan amable la verdad no logro resolver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para el caso que estas planteando hay varias cosas que pueden afectar el funcionamiento. Te voy a enumerar las cosas que deberias revisar:

**Consideraciones dentro de la aplicación**

Asegura que el web.config tenga la siguiente configuración.

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
  ......
</system.web>
```

Para obtener el nombre del usuario en la página (dentro del proyecto Web)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(User.Identity.Name);
}
```

Para obtener el nombre del usuario desde otro proyecto (Ej. una capa de datos referenciada por el proyecto Web)

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
```

**Si el proyecto lo estas depurando con IIS Express**

Asegura que la configuración de la autenticación Windows este correcta (la autenticación anónima tiene que estar deshabilitada, por que si no este será el modo por defecto que va a tomar la aplicación y nunca se va a autenticar con Windows)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Si el proyecto lo vas a ejecutar en IIS Local**

Asegura que la característica "Autenticación de Windows", este instalada en el servidor de IIS. Esto se hace desde la opción "Agregar y Quitar programas" del Sistema Operativo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego verifica que el modo de Autenticación este correctamente configurado en la "Aplicación Web" donde estés haciendo la publicación (la autenticación anónima tiene que estar deshabilitada por la misma razón que explique anteriormente)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yamit amigo disculpa ahora me sale con fin universal  lo adjunte  la imagen en mi pregunta ahora como hago para que salga con mi nombre  nomas

Comment: yamit moreno me sale asi :  FINUNIVERSAL\pflores 

como pudiera hacer para que solo salga pflores

Comment: @Pierro, Correcto, cuando Windows identifica a un usuario lo hace con `<Grupo de trabajo o Dominio>/<Nombre del usuario>` y esto es invariable. Ya lo que puedes hacer es manipular el `string` y recortarle lo que no quieres ver. Para eso hay varios métodos, acá te dejo uno `User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1]`

Comment: Yamit ahora cuando le subido al IIS me pide esto 
como autentificacion window pero yo quiero al abrir solo me abra la pagina y no me pida la autentifacacion adjuntare la imagen que me sale

Comment: @Pierro, esto ya es comportamiento de los navegadores frente a la autenticación Windows (cada navegador tiene su forma de validar y hay navegadores que ni siquiera soportan la autenticación Windows). Si un navegador detecta que esta navegando en una zona segura, como por ejemplo un usuario logueado en el dominio correctamente accediendo a un sitio de la Intranet configurado correctamente, entonces este popup no tendría que salir. Para tu caso el navegador esta detectando una navegación no segura y lo que debes hacer es configurar el navegador para que esa IP quede registrada en una zona segura

Answer (score 0):

En tu `conectionString` agrega `Integrated Security=True;` para que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
<add name="con"  connectionString="server=10.0.101.85\instbdd01; database=Seguridad;  user id=SA; password=SA123456789*; Integrated Security=True;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="conn"  connectionString="server=10.0.101.85\instbdd01; database=BatCliente;  user id=SA; password=SA123456789*; Integrated Security=True;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

La **[documentación oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(VS.71).aspx)** dice:

> Cuando se le asigna valor `false`, se utiliza el ID de usuario y contraseña especificados en la cadena de conexión. Cuando es `true`, se utilizan las credenciales actuales de Windows para realizar la autenticación.

O en su caso, utiliza:

```
txtUsuario.Text = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias amigo pero igual me sigue apareciendo asi como el de la foto ese problema cuando subo al IIS

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar utilizar por un lado:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity
```

Además, deberías tener en cuenta que necesitas tener activada la autenticación de windows en la aplicación correspondiente. En caso contrario es posible que te coja el usuario del propio apppool.

[image: Configuración de la aplicación]

[image: Configuración de la seguridad]